# builtins.AttributeError: 'Timer' object has no attribute 'Start' (threading module issue)

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

So I have some code where I use Threading timers. Here is works just fine:

```
def ice_per_sec(self):
    timer = threading.Timer(1.0, self.ice_per_sec)
    timer.start()  
    self.ice += self.ice_per_second
    self.draw()
```

So here I try to do the exact same thing, but get the error in the title.

```
def minerAnimations(self): 
    timer = threading.Timer(1.0, self.minerAnimations)
    timer.Start()
    self.loaded_miner_image += 1
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? I code with python 3.9 and use WingIDE, if that matters.

Comment: its start() not Start()

Comment: check the first letter because functions and methods are case sensitive.